# independence of random variable and Borel measurable function implying there exists a constant c such that P(g(X) = c) = 1

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Prove for a random variable X and Borel function of random variable g(x) which are independent, then there exists a constant c such that P(g(X) = c) = 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the event $\{g(X) \leq x \}$ for some $x \in \mathbb R$. This event is determined by $g(X)$, and it is also determined by $X$ alone. In other words, it is measurable with respect to the sigma-algebra generated by $g(X)$ and that generated by $X$. Because $X$ and $g(X)$ are independent,
$$ P(g(X) \leq x) = P(\{g(X) \leq x\} \cap \{g(X) \leq x\}) = P(g(X) \leq x)^2 , $$
so that $P(g(X) \leq x)$ must be either 0 or 1. The only random variables with a c.d.f. of this form are the constants.

Comment: I am a little confused on why does X and g(X) being Independent lead to $P(g(X) \leq x) = P(\{g(X) \leq x\} \cap \{g(X) \leq x\})$

Comment: Any event $E$ is equal to its intersection with itself: $E = E \cap E$. Here I'm using this fact with the event $E = \{ g(X) \leq x \}$.